# Print double quotes in file

Tags: bash, files, echo

I would like to print this to a file

```
echo "hello world "today"" > /tmp/file.log
```

have as a result on `/tmp/file.log`

```
hello world "today"
```

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. If the answer worked for you, accept it, or else please post your own answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in many ways

```
$ echo "hello world \"today\"" > /tmp/file.log

$ cat /tmp/file.log
hello world "today"

$ echo 'hello world "today"' > /tmp/file.log

$ cat /tmp/file.log
hello world "today"
```

Comment: I had exactly that answer, I wanted to send today as a variable

    var="today"
    echo "hello world \"$var\" " > /tmp/file.log

Thank you very much for your reply